# "-Nan" value for the total sum of array elements with GPU code

Tags: arrays, sum, opencl

I am working on an OpenCL code which computes the sum of array elements. Every works fine up to a size of 1.024 * 1e+8 for the 1D input array but with 1.024 * 1e+9, the final value is "-Nan".

Here's the source of the code on [this link](http://93.184.46.144/info/test/sumReductionGPU.c)

The Kernel code is on [this link](http://93.184.46.144/info/test/sumReductionGPU.cl)

and the Makefile on [this link](http://93.184.46.144/info/test/Makefile)

Here's the result for the last array size which works (last value of size which works is 1.024 * 1e+8) :

```
$ ./sumReductionGPU 102400000 

Max WorkGroup size = 4100
Number of WorkGroups = 800000

  Problem size = 102400000

  Final Sum Sequential = 5.2428800512000000000e+15

  Final Sum GPU = 5.2428800512000000000e+15

  Initializing Arrays : Wall Clock = 0 second 673785 micro

  Preparing GPU/OpenCL : Wall Clock = 1 second 925451 micro

  Time for one NDRangeKernel call and WorkGroups final Sum  : Wall Clock = 0 second 30511 micro

  Time for Sequential Sum computing  : Wall Clock = 0 second 398485 micro
```

I have taken `local_item_size = 128`, so as it is indicated above, I have `800000 Work-Groups` for `NWorkItems = 1.024 * 1e+8`.

Now If I take 1.024 * 10^9, the partial sums are no more computed, I get a "**-nan**" value for total sum of array elements.

```
$ ./sumReductionGPU 1024000000

Max WorkGroup size = 4100
Number of WorkGroups = 8000000

  Problem size = 1024000000

  Final Sum Sequential = 5.2428800006710899200e+17

  Final Sum GPU =                 -nan

  Initializing Arrays : Wall Clock = 24 second 360088 micro

  Preparing GPU/OpenCL : Wall Clock = 19 second 494640 micro

  Time for one NDRangeKernel call and WorkGroups final Sum  : Wall Clock = 0 second 481910 micro

  Time for Sequential Sum computing  : Wall Clock = 166 second 214384 micro
```

Maybe I have reached the limit of what GPU unit can compute. But I would like to get your advice to confirm this.

If a `double` is `8 bytes`, this will require 1.024 * 1e9 * 8 ~ 8 GBytes for the input array : isn't it too much ? I have only 8 GBytes of RAM.

From your experience, where this issue could come from ?

Thanks

Comment: Please check if one of the `malloc` or `clCreateBuffer` calls fails due to unsufficient memory. Also check if `size_t` is a 32-bit or 64-bit integer on your platform.

Comment: Thanks, the issue comes from clCreateBuffer which fails for 1.024*1e9 work-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already found out, your 1D input array requires a lot of memory. Thus, the memory allocation with `malloc` or `clCreateBuffer` are prone to fail.

For the `malloc`, I suggest to use a helper function `checked_malloc` which detects a failed memory allocation, prints out a message and exits the program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void * checked_malloc(size_t size, const char purpose[]) {
  void *result = malloc(size);
  if(result == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: malloc failed for %s\n", purpose);
    exit(1);
  }
  return result;
}

int main()
{
  double *p1 = checked_malloc(1e8 * sizeof *p1, "array1");
  double *p2 = checked_malloc(64 * 1e9 * sizeof *p2, "array2");
  return 0;
}
```

On my PC which has only 48 GB of virtual memory, the second allocation failes and the program prints:

```
ERROR: malloc failed for array2
```

You can apply this scheme also for `clCreateBuffer`. But, you have to check the result of every OpenCL call anyway. So, I recommend to use a macro for this:

```
#define CHECK_CL_ERROR(result) if(result != CL_SUCCESS) { \
    fprintf(stderr, "OpenCL call failed at: %s:%d with code %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, result); }
```

An example usage would be:

```
cl_mem inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
    nWorkItems * sizeof(double), NULL, &ret);
CHECK_CL_ERROR(ret);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advices